# After running the .bat file, it closes immediately

Tags: batch-file

After running the code below, my .bat file closes immediately

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b | findstr /r "test.*.apk"') DO set var=%%G
echo %var%
cmd /k
```

but if i run a slightly modified version without the matching regex it works fine

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b /s "test-20190201.apk"') DO set var=%%G
echo %var%
cmd /k
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you seen actual warning/error by running it in cmd.exe?

Comment: What do you mean by "closes immediately"? ***What*** "closes immediately"? The command window? How do you run the script? And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Other than one is doing a recursive search and the other not, you need to escape the **`|`** in your first example, to prevent it closing due to error.

Comment: why don't you `dir /b "test*.apk"`? Or even better `for %%G in (test*.apk) do...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b ^| findstr /r "test.*.apk"') DO set var=%%G
echo %var%
cmd /k
```

Otherwise you'll break the `FOR` parser because the pipe is executed with higher prio than the `FOR`